# Paginate laravel collection return 404

Tags: php, laravel

I have paginated my collection and it shows pagination but when I click on page numbers it return 404 error

`Route`

```
Route::post('search', 'front\SearchController@results')->name('search');
```

`Blade (form)`

```
<form action="{{route('search')}}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('POST')
  <input  class="input" type="search" name="q">
</form>
```

`Controller`

```
public function results(Request $request) {
  $q = $request->input('q');
  $rres = array_merge('//my data...');
  $perPage = 12;
  $page = null ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
  $items = $rres instanceof Collection ? $rres : Collection::make($rres);
  $rres = new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, [
    'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
  ]);
  return view('front.pages.new-search', compact('q', 'rres'))->withQuery($q);
}
```

`Blade (pagination)`

```
{{$rres->links('front.pages.search-paginate')}}
// URL of other pages is like:
// http://example.com/search?page=2
// while url of page 1 is like
// http://example.com/search (refer to route code above)
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: You should return the data in your controller method

Comment: @P.K.Tharindu please feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Links only support `GET` and `HEAD` methods, try to add:

```php
Route::get('search', 'front\SearchController@results')->name('search');
```

> **Note** that you only have to add above, no need to remove your `POST`-method from routes.

Comment: So I would have 2 routes? `post` and `get` with same structure?

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Yes, that is how the Web wants it (but you can use `Route::match(['get', 'post'], ...);` to prevent copy and paste)

Comment: that doesn't help, still getting 404

Comment: You will need to clear cache; I think by running `php artisan route:clear` in your root-directory

Comment: In addition, as mentioned by other answers: you should return `JSON` for `post`-method routes (or simply remove anything related to `post`, and change your form to use `GET` instead).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return statement in your `results` method.

```php
return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, [
    'path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()
]);
```

**Edit:**
I see you are returning a view after an HTTP POST which is really a bad design choice. You can google about the PRG Pattern and you will find many articles that will explain why you should always redirect to an HTTP GET which will render your view.

Instead, you should use a GET request for this.

Comment: no I was just forgot to add it here sorry my bad. (edited)